# Array of integers not being stored properly

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, serialization

I have an array of integers made out of a string which is in this format:

```
@var.numbers= "1,2,3,4,5"
```

The integers are then split into an array by:

```
@var.numbers.split(",").map(&:to_i)
```

When printed into the console, the command above puts out an array like it should, but when the following is done:

```
@var.numbers2=@var.numbers.split(",").map(&:to_i)
```

After this command the `@var.numbers2` outputs only 0. It doesn't even show up in array format over the console. Just plain 0. The `@var.numbers` is an `attr_accessor` and `@var.numbers2` is defined as integer in the db and is serialized as an array in the model. Could that be causing an issue ? I have an exact same thing done with ordinary string types and serialized into arrays and it works like a charm. Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numbers2` needs to of type string and not integer. You can't put serialized attributes into an integer column.

Comment: This is what I suspected to be the problem, thanks for the help.

Comment: @Imatejic No problem.